# Searching and updating a certain element in a list

Tags: java

```
class Scorer
{
  List<ScorerLob> scorerLobs;
}

class ScorerLob
{
  List<ScorerInfo> scorerInfos;
}

class ScorerInfo
{
  String name;
  double weight;
}
```

Initially the code reads the default configuration for the values from an XML as below

```
<scorer>
  <scorelob name="A"
   <scorerInfo name = "Pop1" weight="0.5" />
   <scorerInfo name = "Pop2" weight="0.3" />
  </scorelob>
  <scorelob name="B"
   <scorerInfo name = "Pop1" weight="0.75" />
   <scorerInfo name = "Pop3" weight="0.25" />
  </scorelob>
</scorer>
```

In the 2nd step, an xml which has the changed values is read

```
<scorer>
  <scorelob name="A"
   <scorerInfo name = "Pop1" weight="0.8" />
  </scorelob>
</scorer>
```

In this case, only the weight of Pop1 scorerInfo is changed from 0.5 to 0.8. I need to create a deep copy of the default configuration and update the value of the changed setting in that copy.
I keep repeating this process for every XML provided and have a list of different updated settings.

However currently I have to do this via iterating over the entire list. In c++, I could use a std::unordered_set::find to directly get an element. However HashSet dosent seem to support this in Java. Is there a better way of finding/searching an element in the list, updating only its value and not be based on iterating over a list.

Comment: If you want `O(1)` lookup time, then a map is the way to go, rather than a list.

Comment: A <Scorer,Scorer> Map dosent seem like good code.

Comment: No, but a `Map<String,Scorer>`, where the key is the scorer name, will be good code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your class as

```
class Scorer
{
  Map<String, ScorerLob> scorerLobs = new HashMap<>();
}

class ScorerLob
{
  Map<String, ScorerInfo> scorerInfos = new HashMap<>();
}

class ScorerInfo
{
  String name;
  double weight;
}
```

then you can initial your `Scorer` as

```
ScorerInfo scorerInfo1 = new ScorerInfo("Pop1",0.5);
... // other scorerInfos

ScorerLob scorerLob1 = new ScorerLob("A");
scorerLob1.put("Pop1", scorerInfo1);
... // other scorerLobs

Scorer scorer = new Scorer();
scorer.put("A", scorerLob1);
```

And update your `ScorerInfo` as

```
scorer.getScorerLobs().get("A").getScorerInfos().get("Pop1").setWeight(0.8);
```

Comment: instead of getting "Pop1" from scorerInfos map you can directly use put operation to override the value, this would also avoid checking for nulls.